# Scaling/extruding snaps vertices when no snap enabled

Tags: mesh, extrude, scale

When I'm scaling a circle (mesh to give it faces). I hit E then S for Extrude Scale, drag to position (everything is looking good to this point) then when I click to confirm all the verts snap to various other verts.[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Might have something to do with Auto-merge.

Comment: thank you so much! you are a godsend

Comment: For those who see this answer and yet can't find these options at the top of their screen (I couldn't), right-click on the header anywhere near the top of the 3D-View and make sure the "Show Tool Settings" option is checked. It's hard to find a clickable zone for getting the correct right-click menu to show up, but hovering your mouse near clickable elements on the header itself will change your cursor from a target crosshair to a pointer arrow, and that's where you can get the proper menu to pop up when using right-click.